# How to assert 'Exception B' when "Exception A: Exception B" is thrown?

Tags: java, exception, assertj

I want to assert that a certain exception (SSLHandshakeException) is thrown when running some code.

```
assertThatThrownBy(() -> {
        // some code
    }).isInstanceOf(SSLHandshakeException.class);
```

However, this fails because the failure trace says:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting:
  <javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:     Received fatal alert: handshake_failure>
to be an instance of:
  <javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException>
but was:
  <"javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Checking on ProcessingException would work, but is too general. I need to make sure that the code snippet fails because of SSL handshake.

How can I change it in a way that the "second" exception should be considered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [hasCauseInstanceOf](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractThrowableAssert.html#hasCauseInstanceOf-java.lang.Class-).

Comment: .hasCauseInstanceOf(SSLHandshakeException.class); worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A [`getCause()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29) should help here to access the inner exception.

```
assertThatThrownBy(() -> {
        // some code
    }).getCause().isInstanceOf(SSLHandshakeException.class);
```

Comment: I don't have that getCause method, suggest using hasCauseInstanceOf